# New users with only SELECT privileges can DROP tables

Tags: mysql

I created a new user in `mysql` using `phpmyadmin` that only has the `SELECT` privilege.  However, this user can `DROP tables`, delete records, change data (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`).  I have flushed the privileges, logged in and out etc but no change.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output of `show grants for user@host`?

Comment: What database did you create the table in ??? test ???

Answer (score 4):

OK I have some disturbing news for you. If you wrote the tables in a test database, you need to make certains changes.

In a default installation of mysql, test databases are allowed full access to anybody.

To find this out, run `select user,host,db from mysql.db where db like 'test%';`

```
mysql> select user,host,db from mysql.db where db like 'test%';
+------+------+---------+
| user | host | db      |
+------+------+---------+
|      | %    | test    |
|      | %    | test\_% |
+------+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If you see this display when you run this query, **DELETE THESE TWO ROWS IMMEDIATELY !!! (Security hole).** If you don't remove them, note that anonymous users have unlimited firepower on a test database.

Please run these commands to remove that access:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'test%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Please note what [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide says on Page 498 Paragraph 6**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127) in its bulletpoints, especially the last bulletpoint:

> On Unix, MySQL comes with a mysql_secure_installation script that can
>   perform several helpful security-related operations on your
>   installation. The script has the following capabilities:
>
> - Set a password for the root accounts
> - Remove any remotely accessible root accounts.
> - Remove the anonymous user accounts. This improves security because
>     it prevents the possibility of anyone connecting to the MySQL server
>     as root from a remote host. The results is that anyone who wants to
>     connect as root must first be able to log in on the server host, which
>     provides an additional barrier against attack.
> - Remove the test database (If you remove the anonymous accounts, you
>     might also want to remove the test database to which they have
>     access).

Answer (score 1):

Either you have given that user more privileges than just SELECT, or you have started MySQL with `--skip-grant-tables` option.